# Error using object constructor to manage cssClasses

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, object-literal

I wrote a object to manage css Class selectors using javascript.

using literal object is working but not using another OOP way.

Object Literal

```
var className = {
    getList : function(element,cssClass){
        return element.className.split(' ');
    },
    has : function(element,cssClass){
        var classList=element.className.toLowerCase().split(' ');
        return classList.has(cssClass.toLowerCase());
    },
    add : function(element,cssClass){
        if(className.has(element,cssClass)==false){
            element.className+=' '+cssClass;
        }
    },
    remove : function(element,cssClass){

        var index = element.className.toLowerCase().split(' ').indexOf(cssClass.toLowerCase());

        if( index > -1 ){ //found
            var classList=element.className.split(' ');

            classList.splice(index,1);
            element.className=classList.join(' ');
        }
    }
}
```

Constructed Object. (not working)

```
var cssClass = new function(element){
    var that=this;

    this.getList = function(){
        return element.className.split(' ');
    }

    this.has = function(className){
        var classList=element.className.toLowerCase().split(' ');
        return (classList.indexOf(className.toLowerCase())>-1);
    }

    this.add = function(className){
        if(that.has(className)==false){
            element.className = className+' '+element.className;
        }
    }

    this.remove = function(className){

        var index = element.className.toLowerCase().split(' ').indexOf(className.toLowerCase());

        if( index > -1 ){ //found
            var classList=element.className.split(' ');

            classList.splice(index,1);
            element.className=classList.join(' ');
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

`cssClass(d1).add('class1');`

line: 2
message: "'[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating 'cssClass(d1)')"
sourceId: 4600193304

bonus question: this is the best way to manage css classes using javascript? there's a standard api? should I use separated plain functions to write this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `new` from `new function` near the start, as what you are doing is creating a constructor and then calling it immediately. Instead, you need to invoke the constructor when you pass it the element to use. E.g.

```
var cssClass = function(element) {
...
}
```

And then:

```
new cssClass(d1).add('class1');
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/55jkr/1/

To answer the bonus question, the best way to handle CSS classes is to use a standard library, such as jQuery, as these libraries will save you time during the initial implementation and have also been tested. If that's not an option then your approach is fine.